# Spring Inject Map<Qualifier, Bean> instead of Map<String, Bean>

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring setup in which there are multiple instances of the same type for different environments (DEV, PROD). Usually there would only be one environment active and possibly Spring profiles would be used but in this case I need to do comparisons between environments.

So what I would like to do is this:
Given a service of type `MyService` there will be two instances

```
<bean id="devService" class="MyService">
  <!-- DEV config -->
</bean>

<bean id="prodService" class="MyService">
  <!-- PROD config -->
</bean>
```

The class that consumes this now needs to get access to the instances of the different environments.
One way I guess would be to wire in a Map.

```
public MyConstructor(Map<String, MyService> services)
```

In this case I would be stuck with relying on the bean name to figure out what is PROD and what is DEV and I'm not too happy with that.
So I created a qualifier.

```
@Qualifier
public @interface EnvironmentQualifier {
   Environment value();
   public static enum Environment {
     DEV, PROD;
   }
 }
```

Now the beans can be qualified:

```
<bean id="prodService" class="MyService">
  <qualifier type="EnvironmentQualifier" value="PROD" />
</bean>
```

changing the constructor to:

```
public MyConstructor(@EnvironmentQualifier(Environment.PROD) MyService prodService, @EnvironmentQualifier(Environment.DEV MyService devService)
```

works just fine but what I actually want is something like this:

```
public MyConstructor(Map<Environment, MyService> services)
```

but I am not sure if that is possible with Spring or not. Is there a way to define a custom injection strategy maybe? Or are there other ways to solve my problem in general?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But why? Would it even be allowed to have multiple instances of that service? Your code shouldn't be aware of the environment it runs in.

Comment: Agree. Usually only one environment is used and the code is oblivious of that.
In that specific case however it's some sort of a meta project where I need bean instances for different environments (which boils down to the individual bean pulling an input file from a different location) so I can run some analysis on PROD-DEV differences.